# reshape json data using jq

Tags: json, data-manipulation, jq

I'm trying to reshape a json document and I assumed it would be easy to do using jq but I haven't been trying for several hours now and no success ...

(Please note that I'm not a jq jedi and the doc did not help)

I want to go from this :

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "profile": {
        "birthYear": 1900,
        "locale": "en_EN",
        "city": "Somewhere, Around",
        "timezone": "2",
        "age": 52,
        "gender": "m"
      },
      "UID": "SQSQSQerl7XSQSqSsqSQ"
    }
  ]
}
```

to this :

```
{
   "birthYear": 1900,
   "locale": "en_EN",
   "city": "Somewhere, Around",
   "timezone": "2",
   "age": 52,
   "gender": "m",
   "UID": "SQSQSQerl7XSQSqSsqSQ"
}
```

I got what below using this filter : *.results[].profile ,  .results[].UID*

```
{
   "birthYear": 1900,
   "locale": "en_EN",
   "city": "Somewhere, Around",
   "timezone": "2",
   "age": 52,
   "gender": "m"   
}
"UID": "SQSQSQerl7XSQSqSsqSQ"
```

Thanks in advance for your help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine two objects with the addition operator.

`jq '.results[] | .profile + {UID}'`

.profile is already an object.

The other object is created with {}. {UID} is shorthand for {"UID" : .UID}

Answer (score 1):

there are probably better ways but here you go

`jq '.results[0].profile * .results[0] | del(.profile)'`

---

explanation:

merge recursivly container with nested-container by means of `A * B`, then pipe to `del(` to remove nested container

Comment: Indeed less obvious solution but does the trick as well, thanks !